# What does m >>= return means?

Tags: haskell, monads

Was reading tutorial about monads and stuck on following:

```
let m = return 2 :: IO Int
```

That's understandable - we pack 2 in monadic variable(IO 2)
But what does the following mean?

```
m >>= return
```

It outputs 2.

As I know from `Monad` definition, that *return* always accepts exactly one argument. However, here the argument absents. How it could be understood?

Comment: `m >>= return` is equivalent to `m`.

Comment: `return` and `(\x -> return x)` are the same. `m >>= (\x -> return x)` is the same as `do { x <- m ; return x }`. It so happens, due to the Monad Laws, that it is also the same as `do { m }`, or simply `m`. It is also the same as `do { x <- m ; y <- return x ; return y }`, due to the same Monad law.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`(>>=)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) is the *bind* operator. It has signature:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So it expects (on the left side) a monadic object (for instance `IO Int`), and on the right side a function `a -> m b` (for instance `Int -> IO b`) here.

The operator is used to chain operations in a monad together. For instance `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` can be used if we use it like:

```
return "foo" >>= putStrLn
```

So now we `return` a string `"foo"`. The bind operator will unwrap it out of the IO monad so to speak, and pass it to the `putStrLn` function that will print `"foo"` to the standard output channel, and return an `IO ()`. We can then use that `IO ()` for further processing.

Since `return` wraps data into a monad, writing `>>= return` is basically useless. Since for all `x` `x >>= return` should be equal to `x`.

The argument of `return` is not missing in the sense that `>>=` will call the return with an argument. You can also write:

```
m >>= (\x -> return x)
```

but this is equivalent to `m >>= return`.

Comment: How could putStrLn return IO if it only accepts String and doesn't accepts IO as input parameter? (putStrLn :: String -> IO ())

Comment: @BulatM.: because the `>>=` operator *unwraps* the value in the `IO`. Notice that in the type signature, it is not `m a -> (m a -> m b) -> m b`, it is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

Comment: So IO returned by "return" and IO returned(in addition to String) by putStrLn are two different objects?

Comment: @BulatM. no they are not objects, not even types; `IO` is `IO` is the same - it is a marker, a tag that goes together with another type, like `IO String` or `IO Int`, to make a type that *"things"* can have. this is why `IO` is referred to as "type constructor". now, `return 1 :: IO Int` means that `return 1` is a Haskell expression of type `IO Int`. this in turn means, that having `x <- return 1` as part of a `do` block under `main` will cause `x` to refer to a value `1 :: Int`, as the part of the overall *I/O* computation referred to by the value `main :: IO ()`.

Comment: and another *primitive* of the *I/O* "language", `getLine :: IO String` means, having `s <- getLine` under `main` will cause `s :: String` to "hold" i.e. refer to a string, i.e. a value of type `String`. which string? the one the user *will* have typed at the prompt, *when* the `main` is run.